# How can i know when CamelContext was started?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I want to know when CamelContext was started. As i see, DefaultCamelContext has `private Date startDate` field. There is no getter or other methods to get information from this field. All can i get is `getUptimeMillis()` that returns uptime, but this is not what I am looking for.

I know that I can get field value using reflection:

```
Class clazz = context.getClass();
Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField("startDate");
field.setAccessible(true);
Date date = (Date) field.get(context);
```

But I dont think this is good way.

Is there any another way to get this information (may be use another CamelContext, some camel components or services)?

Thank you.

Comment: You could calculate `Instant ccStarted = Instant.now().minusMillis(context.getUptimeMillis())`.

Comment: Thank you. It could be a solution, but maybe there is more beautiful way.

Comment: LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
LocalDateTime startDate = now.minus(camelContext.getUptimeMillis(),
            ChronoField.MILLI_OF_DAY.getBaseUnit());
I haven't tested it but you get the idea

Comment: You could always have a route that starts on startup and saves the date. It would be slightly after startup...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah we can make that as a public API. I created a ticket
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-14266

Otherwise you should do as suggested to calculate the start date via the uptime and minus the current time.